# DBT to redshift connection : 'communication error', OSError('Int or String expected')

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dbt

I have a database in aws redshift. I can read the data from my ec2 using credentials (username/ pass etc.) But when I am trying to connect (from same ec2) to redshift using dbt, the dbt debug command shows this error

1 check failed:
08:08:12  dbt was unable to connect to the specified database.
The database returned the following error:

> Database Error
> ('communication error', OSError('Int or String expected'))

Check your database credentials and try again. For more information, visit:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/configure-your-profile

I double/ triple checked the credentials, they are correct.

also profile name is correct.
my profiles.yml looks like :

```
profile_name_xxx:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      dbname: dev
      host: aws_host_name
      password: xxx
      port: 1111
      schema: staging
      threads: 1
      type: redshift
      user: awsuser
      region: eu-west-x
      cluster_id: xxxx
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue and connect to my db?

Comment: This is an issue with the Python package `redshift_connector` in the most recent version. See https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-redshift/issues/518